# htaccess file causes 404 error

Tags: htaccess, php

I have added the following htaccess file to a directory I want to password protect:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile  /home1/receive2/public_html/ekcepc/memberadmin/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

The `.htpasswd` file is located in the directory `/memberadmin`. Here is the `.htpasswd` file:

```
admin:VAGqZn/ZJ7ltI
```

When I go to the `index.php` file in the `/memberadmin` directory, I get a 404 error. This has never happened to me on other occasions. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why have you tagged your question `php`? What kind of "404 error" are you getting? ie. Is it a system generated/default Apache 404 or a 404 page generated by your web application?

Comment: what happens if you rename .htaccess??

Comment: Agreed that we need more information before we can help. I would first rename the .htaccess file and check whether that is indeed the source of the error.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant lines of the Apache error log, additionally please confirm that your username and password is correctly setup using MD5 or use http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/